# sending multiple customize emails from DB using PHP

Tags: php, email, customization

my script already send the customize emails from the database, the trouble is that depending on the order that they are being called, the email adds the informations of the other client from the query, just on the part of the customize body of the email, because on the emails address and subject its doing correct. That it means the first client receives their information well, the second receives the  first client`s and himself, the third client receives the information of the two first clients and theirs. Its saving the information before send it to the right email...

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultSendEmail)) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSendEmail,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                // create email headers
                $email_from = "xxxx@zzz.com";  
                $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
                'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            // EMAIL Configuration
            $email_to = $row['telEmail'];
            $email_subject = "System access:".$row['telFirstName'].$row['telLastName'];


            // html...
            $email_message .= $row['telFirstName'];
            $email_message .=  '<br>';  
            $email_message .= $row['telEmail'];
            $email_message .=  '<br>';  
            $email_message .= $row['telTelephone'];
             // html...

            mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

  }
}
```

Any help it will be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a loop

`.=` adds to the variable so you keep adding to the `$email_message` for every person, never resting it.

solution change

```
 $email_message .= $row['telFirstName'];
```

to

```
 $email_message = $row['telFirstName'];
```

this resets the variable for each person\email

Comment: Thanks @Dragon for your answer . I apply your advice just at the beginning of my big chain $email_message = '<html>';  and it works, because if I do it for all variables, these are not displayed in the email.